# Grafana Dashboard can't change gridPos width

Tags: grafana

I've been using 'Node Exporter Metrics v2' dashboard for a while now. But recently I added a new node and now with total of 5 nodes it started to cause problems with layout.

'CPU Cores' panel is the problem that causes the layout flow. I tried to change it in JSON Model of dashboard but even though i change the "w" value in `gridPos` it is not changing. Currently it is `"w":6` but after changing it to something else (4 for example) and refreshing i see it still is 6. What is causing this, how can i change it's width ?

Here is the related section (CPU Cores) of JSON model:

```
{
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "QDDFUD1nz"
      },
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "thresholds"
          },
          "mappings": [
            {
              "options": {
                "match": "null",
                "result": {
                  "text": "N/A"
                }
              },
              "type": "special"
            }
          ],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "red",
                "value": 80
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 2,
        "w": 6,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1
      },
      "id": 20,
      "links": [],
      "maxDataPoints": 100,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "none",
        "graphMode": "none",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "horizontal",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "mean"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.3.3",
      "repeat": "node",
      "repeatDirection": "h",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~\"$node\", mode=\"system\"}) or count(node_cpu{instance=~\"$node\", mode=\"system\"})",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "intervalFactor": 2,
          "legendFormat": "",
          "metric": "",
          "refId": "A",
          "step": 14400,
          "target": ""
        }
      ],
      "title": "CPU Cores",
      "type": "stat"
    },
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the solution. I was meddling with the gridPos's 'w' like a fool. It is auto generated appearently. I just added `"maxPerRow": 6,` to corresponding panel JSON content and it automatically set `'w':4.8` after save.

**TL;DR**: Don't try to change 'w' in gridPos. It is auto generated. Change the maxPerRow value or define it if not set.